# How to find date ranges in records with consecutive dates and duplicate data

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2000

There's probably any easy solution for this, but I can't see it.  I have a table with consecutive dates and often duplicate associated data for several of these consecutive dates:

```
Date       Col1  Col2
5/13/2010  1     A
5/14/2010  1     A
5/15/2010  2     B
5/16/2010  1     A
5/17/2010  1     A
5/18/2010  3     C
5/19/2010  3     C
5/20/2010  3     C
```

Using MS T-SQL, I wish to find the start and end dates for each run of distinct Col1 and Col2 values:

```
StartDate  EndDate    Col1  Col2
5/13/2010  5/14/2010  1     A
5/15/2010  5/15/2010  2     B
5/16/2010  5/17/2010  1     A
5/18/2010  5/20/2010  3     C
```

Assumptions:  There are never any missing dates.  Col1 and Col2 are not null.
Any ideas - preferably that don't use cursors?
Many thanks,
-alan

Comment: if you are using Sql Server 2005+, i would answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610599/how-can-i-do-a-contiguous-group-by-in-mysql/1611246#1611246

Answer (score 3):

For SQL 2005+ I think the below should work

```
WITH DATES AS
(
   SELECT COL1, COL2, DATE,
      DATEADD(DAY, -1 * ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER(PARTITION BY COL1, COL2 ORDER BY DATE), DATE) AS GRP
   FROM YOUR_TABLE
)
SELECT COL1, COL2, MIN(DATE) AS STARTDATE, MAX(DATE) AS ENDDATE
FROM DATES
GROUP BY COL1, COL2, GRP
```

If you have any duplicate records, use `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`

For SQL 2000 there is a sub query and a co-related query involved.

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, MIN(DATE) AS STARTDATE, MAX(DATE) AS ENDDATE
FROM (SELECT COL1, COL2, DATE,
    (SELECT MIN(DATE)
     FROM YOUR_TABLE B
     WHERE B.DATE >= A.DATE AND B.COL1 = A.COL1 AND B.COL2 = A.COL2
           AND NOT EXISTS
           (SELECT *
            FROM YOUR_TABLE C
            WHERE C.COL1 = B.COL1 AND C.COL2 = B.COL2
            AND DATEDIFF(DAY, B.DATE, C.DATE) = 1)
    ) AS GRP
    FROM YOUR_TABLE A
)
GROUP BY COL1, COL2, GRP
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using `outer apply`.  Replace `@t` with your table's name.

```
SELECT    head.date, last.date, head.col1, head.col2
FROM      @t head
OUTER APPLY (
          SELECT TOP 1 *
          FROM @t t
          WHERE t.date < head.date
          ORDER BY t.date desc
          ) prev
OUTER APPLY (
          SELECT TOP 1 *
          FROM @t t
          WHERE t.date > head.date
          AND (t.col1 <> head.col1 or t.col2 <> head.col2)
          ORDER BY t.date
          ) next
OUTER APPLY (
          SELECT TOP 1 *
          FROM @t t
          WHERE (t.date < next.date or next.date is null)
          AND (t.col1 = head.col1 and t.col2 = head.col2)
          ORDER BY t.date
          ) last
WHERE (prev.col1 is null or head.col1 <> prev.col1 or head.col2 <> prev.col2)
```

The query first selects the "head" row: rows which start a new group of `col1, col2`.  This is done by looking up the "prev"ious row, and saying it must be different in the `where` clause.

Then it searches for the end of the `col1, col2` group.  That's a two step process: first search for the the first row of the "next" group, and the row before that is the "last" row.

```
Date       Col1  Col2
...
5/15/2010  2     B      <-- "prev" row
5/16/2010  1     A      <-- "head" row
5/17/2010  1     A      <-- "last" row
5/18/2010  3     C      <-- "next" row
...
```

The result of the query matches the example output in your question.

Comment: Nice solution.  I should've mentioned this is for an old sql server 2000 system.

Comment: Alan, you should mark Andomar as the solution if he fits you.